# StandardOutput with CLI application in C# is always empty

Tags: c#, redirectstandardoutput

I'm trying to interact with an old CLI application written in Fortran.

Problem is, I can't even read the output of the program. Reading various SO questions I tried the following code:

```
// Start a new process
Process p = new Process();

// Redirect output and error
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

// Exe path
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\path\to\exe";

// Hook received events
p.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) => Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
p.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) => Console.WriteLine(e.Data);

p.Start();

p.BeginOutputReadLine();
p.BeginErrorReadLine();
```

But.. nothing happens. Replacing the Fortran exe with a generic ipconfig.exe in the System32 folder actually works and I can read the output.

**Update:** while testing back and forth in VS I noticed that when I close the window the correct Output appears for a fraction of a second. **It seems that the output is there but isn't displayed until I close the window**.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Why is `p.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) => Console.WriteLine(e.Data);` repeated twice?

Comment: ErrorDataReceived, hopefully.  There are some temperamental programs around that also require RedirectStandardInput = true in order to work correctly, xcopy.exe is an infamous example.  So next thing to try.

Comment: @mjwills Whops, it was `ErrorDataReceived`. Sorry for that.
@HansPassant Thanks, will give a try. Edit: tried, unfortunately no changes but I noticed something. Please see update in question.

Comment: Does your Fortran executable write to standard output, or to the screen buffer? You can test this by trying to run it from a CMD prompt, and redirecting the output, i.e. ``C:\path\to\exe >output.txt``.

Comment: @dumetrulo Tried from the command, output.txt contains the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Process.BeginOutputReadline() is probably blocking until it receives an new line char.  I would try reading byte-by-byte directly off of the OutputStream object.

Comment: I tried to replace BeginOutputReadline() with a `while(!p.StandardOutput.EndOfStream) { Console.WriteLine(p.StandardOutput.ReadLine(); }` and it behaves like the original. The output is displayed for a fraction only when closing the window. I'm starting to think I'm doing something deeply stupid.